# OpenGL to detect object which the user touches

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a map which is built on OpenGL. This map contains streets, highways, boundary. What I want is to know what object user touches, like is it polygon or polyline or simple line. How can I detect these objects from OpenGL?

Comment: More information is necessary. When you say "user touches," do you mean clicks on or collides with? Generally you do not detect either of these cases with OpenGL (unless you use something like picking using the `selection buffer`).

Comment: i mean click on the streets then i want to know weather the selected item is polygon, polyline or line?

Comment: is there any way to detect these object through opengl?

Comment: Since we are talking about OpenGL ES in this question, no. Very old versions of original OpenGL had something called a selection buffer that would help with this. You are going to need to either use intersection testing or draw everything with a special color and use `glReadPixels (...)`. The process is known as `color picking`, and it may be your only option if you want to select very thin objects like lines.

Comment: Use a physic engine, fastest way to do it!

Comment: @felix any link for this would be highly helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenGL ES, there is no `selection buffer`, so there is no feature specifically designed to allow you to identify the object on screen at a particular point.

You have two options:

1. UnProject the screen space position (x,y) into a world space position and test all objects for intersection against a ray shot through this point (*often the best performing approach*).
2. Render everything in your scene using a special color that uniquely identifies it, and then read the color of the pixel at the screen space position (x,y).

Option 2 is slower because it requires you to wait for the GPU to finish rendering, but it has the advantage of handling very thin objects (such as lines) much more accurately. It is also much simpler to implement.

See the following two links for more details on *Option 2*:

- [Picking with an OpenGL hack | opengl-tutorial.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/clicking-on-objects/picking-with-an-opengl-hack/)
- [OpenGL @ Lighthouse 3D - Picking Tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/index.php3?color1)

Comment: thank for your reply. I forgot to mention all of the objects have different colors

Comment: @MuneemHabib: That is fine, you are only going to render the objects with a color that identifies them uniquely whenever the user clicks on the screen. You should immediately re-draw the scene (after doing `glReadPixels (...)`) the normal way to hide the false colors.

Comment: Additional rendering pass is painful on mobile devices due to low memory bandwidth. Unprojection should be preferred if possible.

Comment: @SergeyK.: Is it possible to accurately test for intersection against line primitives using unprojection? That was the only reason I suggested the hacky color picking -- the problem statement includes lines :-\

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: I know and use color picking on a desktop GPUs. But going mobile is another story. Anyway +1 for the answer.